Booting into recovery mode turns my screen into "Braille" hieroglyphs?
I am running a Ubuntu 22.04 with LUX full disk encryption in a VM. I just finished configuring GRUB to require a password using this answer, and to only require a password when changing settings using this one. And it works great! However, now when I go to GRUB, go to Advanced Options for Ubuntu, and select a option with (recovery mode) at the end, the following messages print to screen:
Loading Linux 5.15.0-88-generic ...
Loading initial ramdisk ...

Then, about two screenfuls of almost Braille-like unintelligible glyphs fill the screen and the system hangs. The only way to leave this screen is to power off.
The hieroglyphs in question
Result of lsblk, showing which partitions are encrypted
My wild guess is that it is trying to read whatever is needed to start recovery mode, which is encrypted, and so I get gibberish. But how do I prevent this, and instead get a screen like in this answer? An acceptable workaround would be booting from a live USB and fixing things that way; I will be testing that next.
